# Why does my FXAS21002 gyrometer return a faulty WHO_AM_I?

Tags: i2c

I'm trying to use the [FXAS21002C gyroscope](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/FXAS21002.pdf) on [BRKT-STBC-AGM04 breakout board](https://www.nxp.com/downloads/en/schematics/BRKT-STBC-AGM04-SCH.pdf).

As a first test I tried to read the WHO_AM_I register at 0x0C, which is supposed to give 0xD7 as a result according to the documentation. But instead I am reading 0x00.

I monitored the I2C communication and I'm not noticing any irregularities there. The FXAS21002C is responsing with ACK's. etc

(Upper line is SCL; lower line is SDA; both pulled to 3.3V)
[image: (upper line is SCL, lowerline is SDA)]

The conversation here is:
010000000 000011000  010000010 000000001

And I'm running the following code on my Arduino Uno:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Arduino.h"

#define GyrAddress 0x20

#define pullupPin 4

#define gyr_WHO_AM_I 0x0C
#define gyr_WHO_AM_I_RSP 0xD7

#define I2C_address GyrAddress
#define WHO_AM_I gyr_WHO_AM_I
#define WHO_AM_I_RSP gyr_WHO_AM_I_RSP

uint8_t readRegister(uint8_t address) {
    uint8_t output;

    Wire.beginTransmission(I2C_address);
    Wire.write(address);
    Wire.endTransmission();

    delayMicroseconds(4);

    Wire.requestFrom(I2C_address, 1);
    while (Wire.available()) {
        Serial.println("reading a thing");
        output = Wire.read();
    }

    return output;
}

void writeRegister(uint8_t address, uint8_t value){
    Wire.beginTransmission(I2C_address);
    Wire.write(address);
    Wire.write(value);
    Wire.endTransmission();
}

bool initialize() {
    Wire.begin();
    Wire.setClock(400000);        // I2C fast mode, 400kHz
    uint8_t reg;
    if ((reg = readRegister(WHO_AM_I)) != WHO_AM_I_RSP) { //Could not find MAG3110

        Serial.println(reg);
        Serial.println(WHO_AM_I_RSP);
        Serial.println("Could not find gyro connected!");
        return false;
    } else //Successfully initialized
    {
        Serial.println("found gyro!");
        return true;
    }
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(pullupPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    Serial.begin(57600);

    Serial.println("begun");

    Serial.println(initialize());
}

int pullup;
void loop() {
    // test code to rerun when I press a button.
    int input = digitalRead(pullupPin); 
    if(input ^ pullup){
      pullup = input;
      if(input){
        Serial.println(initialize());
      }
    }
}
```

Schematic of my current setup:
[image: circuit drawing]

Does someone know why the FXAS21002C is not returning the WHO_AM_I response that is listed in the documentation?

Comment: Any differences at 100kHz?

Comment: the goofy part about your post is that you are asking about WHO_AM_I data exchange, but you post a waveform for something else

Comment: Did you expect us to read the read last picture? I ask this because it's not possible to read it because 1) the contents on the image is tiny because the image itself is rather small. Even zooming in would create a blurry mess. 2) the writing is faded and you cannot read the labels. I tried photoshopping this image where you can read it clearly but due to inconsistant lighting and faded labels, I could not reproduce a better quality picture. I couldn't read some of the labels on your block diagrams and some of the resistor values.

Comment: @jsotola this waveform is for asking the WHO_AM_I. 

The first 18 bits is the arduino telling which register he wants to read:
0100000 0 0   00001100 0 -> 
7 bits for the device adress 0x20,
1 write-bit, 
1 bit pulled low by the device as an ACK,

8 bits data: the register adress 0x0C of WHO_AM_I,
1 bit ack by the device

Comment: @KingDuken: I made a new picture. I hope this helps?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I just tried 100kHz. This gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly wrong answer with some further reading required...

From the gyro's manual (p.15)

> A LOW-to-HIGH transition on the SDA line while SCL is high is defined as a stop
>   condition (SP) signal. A write or burst write is always terminated by the master
>   issuing the SP signal. A master should properly terminate a read by not
>   acknowledging a byte at the appropriate time in the protocol. A master may also issue
>   a repeated start signal (SR) during a transfer.

and (re: single byte read)

> The MCU transmits an SR, followed by
>   the byte containing the slave address and the R/W bit set to “1” for a read

Putting these together with your scope plot, you are writing the WHOAMI address then issuing a SP (STOP) signal, instead of an SR (Start Repeated) signal.

This appears to terminate the transaction...

IMO the documentation is incomplete and should be supplemented by the I2C protocol specification (UM10204) , which, issued by a rival company, Freescale aren't in any hurry to help you find with anything so useful as a [link](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf).

See page 9 of UM10204:

> The bus stays busy if a repeated START (Sr) is generated instead of a STOP condition. In
>   this respect, the START (S) and repeated START (Sr) conditions are functionally identical.

(the difference between SR and STOP being, I believe, that you bring SDA high while SCL is still low so the next SDA falling edge starts the next transfer : confirmed by Figure 6 on p.10)

So in your ReadRegister code

```
Wire.beginTransmission(I2C_address);
Wire.write(address);
Wire.endTransmission();

delayMicroseconds(4);
Wire.requestFrom(I2C_address, 1);
```

I believe `Wire.endTransmission()` is incorrect and you need some other function (or possibly none at all) to continue the transmission and collect the data.

That is where the further reading comes in; I find it easier to program my Arduinos in Ada so I can't help you find the right function in the Arduino library.

But a quick search shows the [EndTransmission documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireEndTransmission) which says

> As of Arduino 1.0.1, endTransmission() accepts a boolean argument changing its behavior for compatibility with certain I2C devices.
>
> If true, endTransmission() sends a stop message after transmission,
>   releasing the I2C bus.
>
> If false, endTransmission() sends a restart message after
>   transmission. The bus will not be released, which prevents another
>   master device from transmitting between messages. This allows one
>   master device to send multiple transmissions while in control.
>
> The default value is true. Syntax
>
> Wire.endTransmission()
>   Wire.endTransmission(stop)
>
> Parameters
>
> stop : boolean. true will send a stop message, releasing the bus after
>   transmission. false will send a restart, keeping the connection
>   active.

Comment: Thank you! This was indeed the issue, and passing false with Wire.endTransmission() fixed it!